# How to display sms in inbox in the form of popups?

Tags: android, sms

I have seen the sms in my phone and other phones being shown as a `popup` kind of thing.`I know how to show the sms from inbox in the form of ListView`.I have searched a lot,but did not get the way to Show the sms like `PopUp` kind of thing in android.Can anybody please help me in this regard?Thanks in advance.

[image].

Comment: Do you mean when you got new message a popup window display with content of new message ? Or widget at homescreen?

Comment: No sir,i want to show the messages in my inbox in a popup kind of window.I know how to show them in a list,but i want to show them as kind of popups like my android phone is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below link may help you for showing the sms in popups

http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/android-custom-sms-popup-part

Comment: Thanks sir,but this is not the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, what you need to do is:

1. Register a BroadcastReceiver with an SMS reception intent filter in your manifest (don't forget permissions)

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.tam.receivers.YourReceiver" >
       <intent-filter >
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SMS_RECEIVED" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
   ```
2. Start a background service in the onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver

   public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   ```
       Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
           context.startService(startServiceIntent);
   }
   ```

   }
3. open a dialog from the service

Comment: Sorry,but this is not my question.My question is how to show the sms in form of popup kind of way(I think you must have seen it in your phone or so)

Comment: do you mean a popup dialog, or a notification?